# ExtractSubDataset in ArcPy loop giving ERROR 999999?

Tags: arcpy, error-999999, group-layer, extract

In ArcMap, I've created a layer group that I would like to add extracted subdatasets from a file to.  It is a .grb file and I've successfully done this with the provided "Extract Subdataset" tool.  Is it possible to do this in python with a loop to name each out_raster in the group according to index?  For example, 
for subdataset_index = "00", then 
out_raster = "filename+"010"+" and so on for all indices in the original file?  I've seen this done manually with the batch method, but I have 44 subdatasets to extract in each file.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
idx = 0
while idx < 10:
  in_ras = "C:/Data/gribFile.grb"
  out_ras = "C:/ArcGIS/geoDB.gdb/Grb_+'FL'+idx+'10'"
  arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(in_ras, out_ras, idx)
  idx = idx+1
```

I guess I'm getting stuck on how to grab each index from each file as object.  Below is error I'm getting.

> Error message: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 8, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 14129, in
>   ExtractSubDataset     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error
>   executing function. The table name is invalid. No spatial reference
>   exists. Invalid function arguments Invalid function arguments An
>   invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT ObjectID, UUID, Type FROM
>   GDB_Items WHERE PhysicalName = 'Grb_+'FL'+IDX+'10'' AND Type IN
>   ('{70737809-852C-4A03-9E22-2CECEA5B9BFA}')] Failed to execute
>   (ExtractSubDataset).

---

Was able to get it working with this:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
#Levels array
lvs = {myArray}

for ftLevel in lvs:     
level = ftLevel
FL = lvs[ftLevel]
gFile = "C:/filepath"
gFileDate = "G_2016"
gFileHour = "000HR"
gRasterFileloc = "C:/filepath/raster"
in_ras = gFile+gFileDate+gFileHour+".grb"
out_ras = gRasterFileloc+gFileDate+gFileHour+FL
arcpy.ExtractSubDataset_management(in_ras, out_ras, level)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Questions asking for help with code should include a snippet of the code you've actually tried, and details on where you are stuck.  Please [edit] your question to include any extra information.  The answer to your question "Is it possible to do this in python" is more than likely just "Yes, it is possible"

Comment: thanks Midavalo. I've updated with where I started in arcpy.

Comment: Are receiving any errors, if so please include those messages into the question.

Comment: I've attached the error I'm getting.  Hoping this is syntax.